# What's wrong with my loader?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to load some image before using them in the canvas. I created a function that wait the 'onload' and then run the mainloop, but sometimes it doesn't work...

here's the code :

```
  var imagesSrc = ['paris.jpg','Paris','shanghai5.jpg','Shangai','beijing.jpg','Beijing','brslondon.jpg','London','madrid.jpg','Madrid','luxembourg.jpg','Luxembourg','dubai.jpg','Dubai','geneve.jpg','Geneva','sino.jpg','Shanghai','swaar.jpg','Mumbai','singapore2.jpg','Singapore','hongkong.jpg','Hong Kong'];
  for (var i = imagesSrc.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=2) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.name = imagesSrc[i];
    image.onload = function()
    {
      load++;
      if(load >= imagesSrc.length*0.5){
        ImageGenerator(game , 6000);
      }
    }
    image.src = 'assets/images/illus/'+imagesSrc[i-1];
    game.images.push(image);
  }
```

It looks fine to me...

Can someone help me?

thx!

Comment: How does it sometimes not work?

Comment: The problem is that i have to reload the page to see the image on the canvas :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this like:

```
  function imgTest(){
      var imagesSrc = ['paris.jpg','Paris','shanghai5.jpg','Shangai','beijing.jpg','Beijing','brslondon.jpg','London','madrid.jpg','Madrid','luxembourg.jpg','Luxembourg','dubai.jpg','Dubai','geneve.jpg','Geneva','sino.jpg','Shanghai','swaar.jpg','Mumbai','singapore2.jpg','Singapore','hongkong.jpg','Hong Kong'];
  for (var i = imagesSrc.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=2) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.name = imagesSrc[i];
  image.onload = function()
  {
  load++;
  if(load >= imagesSrc.length*0.5){
    ImageGenerator(game , 6000);
  }
}
image.src = 'assets/images/illus/'+imagesSrc[i-1];
game.images.push(image);
}
  }
```

And call this like:

```
 window.onload=imgTest;
```

Comment: I already did that, this part of code is in the windows.onload = function ^^.

The problem is that i have to reload the page to see the image on the canvas :/